# A delay occurs when i run the script

Tags: powershell, event-log

This is my script to get event log of a specific time.

```
$time = Get-WinEvent microsoft-windows-dns-client/operational -MaxEvents 1 | 
Select-Object @{name="time"; expression={$_.timecreated.tostring("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")}} | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty time

Get-WinEvent microsoft-windows-dns-client/operational | 
Where-Object {$_.timecreated.tostring("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") -eq "$time"}
```

If i run the script, shows results.

And script exits after 60 seconds or more delay occurs.

What is my mistake?

[image]

[Second question]

Is this powershell bug?

This situation is that script does not exit after shows results.

[image]

3 seconds are required for this result of the image below.

[image]

Why so slow?

Does powershell has a bug about time condition?

**I think solved this problem. Thanks gms0ulman.**

```
while($true) {

    $QUERY = @"
    <QueryList><Query><Select Path='Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Client/Operational'>
       *[System/EventID = 3006] and 
       *[System/TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 60000]] and
       *[EventData/Data[@Name='QueryType'] != 28]
    </Select></Query></QueryList>
"@

    $CMD = (Get-WinEvent -FilterXml $QUERY).count 2>$null

    if($CMD -ne 0) {
       $LOG_LIST = Get-WinEvent -FilterXml $QUERY | Select-Object timecreated, processid, message | Sort-Object timecreated

       foreach($LOG in $LOG_LIST) {
          $TIMESTAMP = $LOG | Select-Object -ExpandProperty timecreated
            $TIMESTAMP_SPLIT = $TIMESTAMP -split " "
            $LOG_DATE = $TIMESTAMP_SPLIT[0]
            $LOG_TIME = $TIMESTAMP_SPLIT[1]
            $PROC_ID = $LOG | Select-Object -ExpandProperty processid
            $PROC_NAME = Get-Process -id $PROC_ID | Select-Object -ExpandProperty processname
            $MSG = $LOG | Select-Object -ExpandProperty message
            $URL_1 = $MSG -replace '^\S{2}\s([^,]+).+','$1'
            $URL_2 = $URL_1 -replace '^.*?([^.]+\.[^.]+\.?|[^.]+\.(ac|co|go|ne|nm|or|pe|re)\.[^.]+\.?)$','$1'
            $LOG_SET = "$LOG_DATE`t$LOG_TIME`t$PROC_ID`t$PROC_NAME`t$URL_1`t$URL_2"
            $LOG_SET >> C:\dns.csv
            }
        }

    Start-Sleep 60
    }
```

Comment: Consider following command: `1..1e9|?{$_-lt10}`. Are you expecting it return immediately as print `9`, because no other number can possibly match condition? Or it should process and discard all other numbers, which will take some time?

Comment: @PetSerAl My script displays all the results, but does not exit immediately. I want to exit script immediately after shows results.

Comment: But, how do you know that script already display ***all*** the results? More importantly, how does script can know that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the `$time` variable contains what you expect. On my machine the selection criteria `microsoft-windows-dns-client/operational` is not valid.

I believe this is what you're after:

```
# Get event based on your criteria. Implicitly converted to datetime data type
# You can check by running $time.GetType() or $time | gm
[datetime]$time = (Get-WinEvent microsoft-windows-dns-client/operational -MaxEvents 1).TimeCreated

# Get events where the TimeCreated field matches the previous time.
Get-WinEvent microsoft-windows-dns-client/operational | Where-Object {$_.TimeCreated -eq "$time"}
```

**Edit - I was wrong, that's not what you're after**

Initially, I tried to restrict the EventLogs to those in the last day. Then the last minute. But I still got the lag you mention.

For me the solution was to use the `-FilterXML` parameter as described in [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/04/14/using-get-winevent-filterxml-to-process-windows-events/). Of course it will need customisation to point from the PowerShell events to match your needs

```
# xml source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/04/14/using-get-winevent-filterxml-to-process-windows-events/
[xml]$filterXml = @"
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Windows PowerShell">
    <Select Path="Windows PowerShell">*[System[(Level=4 or Level=0)]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
"@

[datetime]$time = (Get-WinEvent -FilterXml $filterXml -MaxEvents 1).TimeCreated

Get-WinEvent -FilterXml $filterXml | Where-Object {$_.TimeCreated -eq $time}
```

Comment: Powershell can access to event log only that registered to registry(HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog). And your script shows running command prompt only. You can try another event log name like system. thank you:)

Comment: @Mr.kang Thanks - initially I left the particular LogName unspecified so it just got the latest entry. Explicitly casting `$time` to `[datetime]` = it works in ISE. Regarding the slowness, please see updated answer using `-FilterXML`